# Create dictionary of dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a dictionary for year and month. Its a kind of macro which i can call over required no. of year and month. I am facing challenge while adding dynamic column in pyspark df

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo1",'2016-1-31'),(1, "test",'2016-1-31'), (2, "bar1",'2012-1-3'),(4, "foo2",'2011-1-11')], ("k", "v","date"))
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(col('date').desc())          
df = df.withColumn("next_date",lag('date').over(w).cast(DateType()))
df = df.withColumn("next_name",lag('v').over(w))
df = df.withColumn("next_date",when(col("k") !=  lag(df.k).over(w),date_add(df.date,605)).otherwise(col('next_date')))
df = df.withColumn("next_name",when(col("k") != lag(df.k).over(w),"").otherwise(col('next_name')))

import copy
dict_of_YearMonth = {}

for yearmonth in [200901,200902,201605 .. etc]:

    key_name = 'Snapshot_'+str(yearmonth)
    dict_of_YearMonth[key_name].withColumn("test",yearmonth)
    dict_of_YearMonth[key_name].withColumn("test_date",to_date(''+yearmonth[:4]+'-'+yearmonth[4:2]+'-1'+''))
 # now i want to add a condition 
  if(dict_of_YearMonth[key_name].test_date >= dict_of_YearMonth[key_name].date) and (test_date <= next_date) then output snapshot_yearmonth  /// i.e dataframe which satisfy this condition i am able to do it in pandas but facing challenge in pyspark
dict_of_YearMonth[key_name]  
dict_of_YearMonth
```

Then i want to concatenate all the dataframe into single pyspark dataframe, i could do this in pandas as shown below but i need to do in pyspark

```
  snapshots=pd.concat([dict_of_YearMonth['Snapshot_201104'],dict_of_YearMonth['Snapshot_201105']])
```

If is any other idea to generate dictionary of dynamic data frame with dynamic addition of columns and perform condition and generate year based data frame and merge them in single data frame. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried below code is working fine

```
// Function to append all the dataframe using union
def unionAll(*dfs):
return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

// convert dates
def is_date(x):
    try:
        x= str(x)+str('01')
        parse(x)
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        pass # if incorrect format, keep trying other format

dict_of_YearMonth = {}
for yearmonth in [200901,200910]:
key_name = 'Snapshot_'+str(yearmonth)
dict_of_YearMonth[key_name]=df
func =  udf(lambda x:  yearmonth, StringType())
dict_of_YearMonth[key_name] = df.withColumn("test",func(col('v')))
default_date = udf (lambda x : is_date(x))
dict_of_YearMonth[key_name] = dict_of_YearMonth[key_name].withColumn("test_date",default_date(col('test')).cast(DateType()))
dict_of_YearMonth
```

To add mutiple dataframes use below code:

```
final_df = unionAll(dict_of_YearMonth['Snapshot_200901'],  dict_of_YearMonth['Snapshot_200910'])
```